# mysql - insert results of query into same table with joins

Tags: mysql, sql-update, left-join, mariadb

I use this site all the time to find answers to my questions but this is the first time I've ask one.

I have two tables and want to query both tables and insert the results into two columns on table 1. Something like this:

```
SELECT a.column1 from table1 a LEFT Join ( SELECT 'column1' from 'table2' ) AS a ON where a.column1 like '%column1.table2%';
```

Basically then insert the result into column5 and column6 on table 1

I know that this isn't correct as it doesn't work and it's not going to update any thing. For testing I'm running select statements to verify before running the update command. Another way of saying what I need would be:

If column1 in table1 is like column1 in table2 then update column5 in table1 with corresponding entry from column2 in table2 and update column6 in table1 with column7 from table1 with corresponding entry in column3 from table2;

I realize that this is not the best explanation but that is the best way I can explain what I want. Please ask questions if more information is needed and I will do my best to explain.

Thanks for any input you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can do multi-table updates in a single update statement using joins in the table list:

```
update t1 inner join t2 on t1.column1 like concat('%',t2.column1, '%')
set t1.column5=t2.column2, t1.column6=t2.column7
```

However, using like is not necessarily the best idea, since more than 1 records from t2 may match the same record within t1, therefore a single t1 record may be updated several times during a single run.

Your description of which t1 fields should be updated by which field from t2 is inaccurate, cannot really tell the logic there.